# `func azure functionapp list-functions` returns unauthorised, 401

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy a function app using CLI and VS code plugin, and as the title states receiving 401. I tried logging out and in: when logged out the error is different.
Documentation suggests checking Storage account keys - checked, rotated, doesn't help.

As mentioned in the title even the command to list functions don't work. I'm all out of ideas.

To deploy I use Terraform, and tried to delete and redeploy the function app: no changes.

Here is my function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the TF block:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "data-extract-fa" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-function-app"
  resource_group_name = var.rg
  location            = var.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.data-extract-sa.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.data-extract-sa.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.data-extract-sp.id
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  app_settings = {
    AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage    = true
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = azurerm_application_insights.data-extract-ai.instrumentation_key
    SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
  }

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.9"
    }
  }

  dynamic "connection_string" {
    for_each = { for tuple in regexall("(.*)=(.*)", file("../functions/.env")) : tuple[0] => tuple[1] }
    content {
        name = connection_string.key
        type = "Custom"
        value = connection_string.value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer: the solution was the following:

- remove the connection strings block
- `terraform apply`
- add the block back
- `terraform apply`

Works.

If someone could explain to me why it works that way, I would be grateful. Thanks.